# jQuery showing an element if a main wrapper is clicked, but not if a specific element is clicked

Tags: jquery, click, onclick

I'm having troubles with a simple menu hide/show with jQuery.

The HTML markup is as follows:

```
<div class="content borderRad5" id="mainWrapper">

    <div id="ticketControl" class="noPrint blackBoxShadow">
        <span id="printThis" class="TicketButton">Print</span>
        <span id="emailThis" class="TicketButton">Email as Word</span>
            <div id="emailDoc" class="blackBoxShadow borderRad5">
                <div class="underline">Email to:</div>
                <label>Email</label> 
                <span>
                    <input type="text" class="smallText" />
                </span>
            </div>
        <span id="wordThis" class="TicketButton">Save as Word</span>
        <span id="addToLoyalty" class="TicketButton">Add to Account</span>
        <span id="addNote" class="TicketButton">Add Note</span>
        <span id="refundThis" class="TicketButton">Refund</span>
    </div>

  ---- THE REST OF THE PAGE ----

</div>
```

`#ticketControl` is a hidden div containing the menu. When the mouse is clicked anywhere within the `.content` div, I want it to slide into view. The jQuery below does this just lovely.

```
    $('.content').live('click', function () {
        $('#ticketControl').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

However, I have a second hidden div within this main menu `#emailDoc` which needs to slide into view when `#emailThis` is clicked, obviously this is easy, BUT, I can't stop it from hiding the menu again.

I realise why it's doing it, because anything within `.content` triggers the slideToggle function as above, but I can't seem to stop it, I've tried using `.not('.TicketButton')` and also trying to get parent IDs and excluding them and so on, but I'm clearly missing something obvious!

Any help much appreciated (and yes, I realise I should be using jquery `on` but I'm sticking with `live` for now...!)

Comment: Do you *have* to use `live`? Are you inserting the elements dynamically? Once clicked on, `#emailDoc`, you just have to prevent the event from bubbling up. This could be tricky though if you use `live`.

Comment: I don't have to use `live` actually, no, but I still can't get it to work. I tried `$('.content').not('#ticketControl').click(function () {
            $('#ticketControl').slideToggle('slow');
        });` but it makes no difference... why is it ignoring the `not`?

Comment: `.not` is filtering the set of elements. So you are saying: *Select all elements with class `content` and remove the one with ID `ticketControl`*.

Comment: ... shouldn't that therefore stop the `click` event from being captured within the element with ID `ticketControl`?

Comment: No. It is only reducing the set of selected elements. `$('.content')` selects one element. `.not('#ticketControl')` would remove that one element if it had the ID `ticketControl`. Then you bind the event handler to new resulting set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you don't have to use `live`, directly attach the click event handler to both elements and call [`event.stopPropagation()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent the event from bubbling up and triggering other event handlers:

```
$('.content, #emailThis').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

---

If you cannot use the event handler like this, I suggest you use generic classes which associate elements with their children which have to toggled. For example the elements which should have such a behaviour could have the class `header` and the children which are supposed to be toggled `toggle` (sorry, I'm a bit uncreative at the moment):

```
$('.header').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.toggle').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Otherwise you have to duplicate basically the same behaviour for a couple of elements, which reduces maintainability of your code.

Comment: I've confused this by not quite showing my full markup. There's loads more within the `.content` div which is to remain. Your code works, but can't work in my situation, because I need explicitly declare which element to `slide` (ie #ticketControl), doing this with your code to give `$('.content, #emailThis').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('#ticketControl').slideToggle('slow');
        });` breaks it

Comment: @Jamie: Then bind to separate event handlers, although I would stay away form such hardcoded solutions. See my update.

Comment: argh! OK, that's not how I hoped to do it, but it'll do! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call `event.stopPropagation()` in the click callback function for `#emailThis` so that the event doesn't bubble up the DOM to the parent elements.